# Cloud Dataflow job was successful, but resources weren't torn down/destroyed afterwards

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Ran our CDF job today, and it was successful. The ID is:

**2015-03-12_16_45_27-1664852687091388734**

However, when the job was finished its VM's/instances were not torn down as they normally are. I had to manually delete them all (100).

Why were the resources not torn down after the job completed?

**--Edited Update--**

We have another job which completed, but the resources were not torn down afterwards: **2015-03-17_21_27_12-7893426695197902407**

Comment: The fix is now live.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. This is a known issue that we will have a fix for in the next release of the managed service. I'll update this thread when this is live, and thank you for your patience.

**Update**

The fix is now live.